# Launch Jitsi Meet App on Mobile from QR code?

Tags: android, ios, qr-code, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm doing an event where some people will be walking around with mobile phones and at several locations there will be QR codes. The mobile phone users need to be able to scan the QR codes to get into a face-to-face chat with distant participants on laptops.  I'm planning on using Jitsi Meet as the video chat application.  As the people walking around will have registered in advance, I can ask them to install the Jitsi Meet app, which seems more reliable than whatever random web browsers they might have. They will likely be a mixture of iPhone and Android users.

What I need to know is how to get from the QR code to the app.  Do QR codes support a custom uri?  What is the uri for jitsi meet? Is it the same across android and ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we generated QR codes based on the room URLs. When users on mobile devices scanned the codes, jitsi meet served them a web page asking if they wanted to use the app or proceed with their web browser. It worked flawlessly. I highly recommend this as a way to site-specific telepresence.

Comment: What that means is that the browser knows how to launch the app into the desired room.  And that means there must be a way to skip the browser and directly launch the app into a specific room.  Is there documentation on how to do this?